# Shiny server for windows

Tags: shiny, windows-server-2012-r2, shiny-server

`Shiny server` is available for Ubuntu.

Is there any way to use it in `Windows Server 2012 R2` without setting a virtual machine on server?

Could this be a solution https://github.com/nsh87/shinyVM to provide a public link instead of localhost?

Comment: Suppose this script can't used for Windows https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source

Comment: Anyone who had the same issue for windows?